# Which statistical test should I use for my assigned participants

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, t-test, psychology

I am trying to analyse the interaction between level of class (either upper class or lower class) and level of prejudice attitudes. I have hypothesized that upper class individuals shall have higher levels of prejudice due to eliciting more essentialist beliefs. I am using the Essentialist Belief Scale, the Modern Racism Scale and the Modern Sexism Scale.

What statistical test should I be running?

I thought it could be a $t$-test or a regression but I am not entirely sure which one to use and why.

Comment: What kind of data do you have?

Comment: I have no data at the moment just trying to assess how to analyse this hypothesis

Comment: That's a good idea.  But before you can even think about a statistical test you need to have some sense of what data you can collect!

Comment: @KEA, It is good to see a question about statistical methodology asked so early in the course of research! Ronald Fisher famously said, "To consult the statistician after an experiment is finished is often merely to ask him to conduct a *post mortem* examination. He can perhaps say what the experiment died of."

Answer (score 1):

@KEA, you are clearly developing causal hypotheses, and I wonder if you have considered diagramming them using *directed acyclic graphs* (DAGs). For example, just reading your original post, and adding some imagination about what data you might collect, I'm led to sketch the following causal diagram:
 [image: An example of a causal diagram for your research question]

Your own diagram of your hypotheses may be quite different from this. But I'll wager that no sooner will you have drawn your own causal diagram than you will see that your research question is genuinely nontrivial, and cannot possibly reduce to a handful of null hypothesis tests.

FYI: This diagram is made using the [DOT language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)), like so:

```
digraph g {
  node [fontname="Helvetica"]
  SC [label="Social\nClass"]
  EB [label="Essentialist\nBeliefs"]
  PA [label="Prejudiced\nAttitudes"]
  EBS [label="EB\nscore"]
  MRS [label="Racism\nScore"]
  MSS [label="Sexism\nScore"]
  SRSC [label="Self-reported\nSocial Class"]
  SC -> EB -> EBS
  EB -> PA
  PA -> MRS
  SC -> MRS
  PA -> MSS
  PA -> SRSC [style="dotted", label="?"]
  SC -> SRSC
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you measuring class as simply a dichotomous variable (upper or lower are the only possible values)?  If so, the simplest analysis would be three t-tests, one for each scale measure.

But class feels like it should be a continuous variable - in which case regressions would be appropriate.

At a higher level of analysis, this sounds like it would benefit from a multivariate analysis, in which the three outcome measures are considered simultaneously (MANOVA if you are working with dichotomous class variable).

Comment: Thank you for helping me.I am using it as a dichotomous variable, so how would I explain the design if I were to use a MANCOVA, would it be a 2 x 2 MANCOVA?

Comment: Would I be better substituing the racism and sexism scales for just the stereotype one and if so what anaylse should I use

Comment: @KEA what is your research question?  It sounded initially like the three scales were all meant to be indices of prejudice - just different forms.  So you would have three dependent measures and one factor (class).  If so, it wouldn't be a MANCOVA as you have no covariate (that you've listed).  And you only have one factor (class) so it would be the multivariate equivalent of a t-test. (So not 2x2, which implies two factors)

Comment: @KEA to answer the second part of your question - if you ditched the racism and sexism scales, you'd only have one DV and you'd be doing a simple t-test.

Comment: My research question is Is there an interaction between social class and prejudice,

Comment: @KEA I wouldn't personally use the word interaction that way.  If I'm understanding it correctly, you are wanting to ask if mean prejudice levels are different in people from different classes.  Is this correct?  So class is measured somehow (and you've put people into high vs low) and you have three different measures of prejudice?

Comment: yes that is what I'm trying to say sorry im not great at explaining myself

Comment: Sorry I'm struggling to decide upon what I want to analyse, but think if I included 4 scale, 1 on essentialist beliefs, 1 on stereotypes and hierarchical justification and then 1 on sexcism and 1 on racism, making it 4 dependent variables, an one factor  (class) would i be running multiple regression?

Comment: @KEA multiple regression is for cases where you have a single DV - you seem to have four.  So no, not multiple regression.  Either four separate analyses (one for each DV), each with a single factor (so t-tests) OR one multivariate analysis with 4DVs and 1 factor (so MANOVA equivalent to t-test).

Comment: Okay so if i used 3 measures of prejudice - DV and 1 factor (class) what statistical test would I want to be using?

Comment: For simultaneous consideration of the DVs you'd be using a MANOVA  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_analysis_of_variance  - the specific form would be a Hotelling's T-squared https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution

Comment: @KEA, it sounds to me from your initial question that your research question may in fact be a richer one, based in some theoretical models of social class, certain types of belief, etc. Are you maybe attempting to throw your hypothesis down onto the Procrustean bed of null hypothesis significance testing? There's at least one psychology journal where you wouldn't even be able to publish your p-value! http://www.nature.com/news/psychology-journal-bans-p-values-1.17001

Comment: John Kruschke is a psychologist with an accessible introduction to alternative approaches suitable for building and investigating models full of the kind of latent variables you allude to in your original post. https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/about-the-author

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help! It is greatly appreciated!